# Logging 500 Error Traceback through Middleware

Tags: python, django

I want to log the traceback that occurs during a 500 internal server error. I've set up middleware that I was hoping would do this:

```
import traceback
import sys

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ProcessExceptionMiddleware(object):
    '''
    Log exceptions and tracebacks any time an exception is encountered
    '''

    def process_response(self, request, response):·
        if response.status_code == 500:
            logger.info('\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
        return response
```

Alas, when a 500 error occurs and this middleware is triggered, sys.exc_info() returns (None, None, None). The `response` itself is a string that contains the traceback, but it's a weirdly formatted string that isn't easily parseable. I'd like to have the traceback formatted in a nice list format like sys.exc_info() would give me. How can I get this working?

Note that process_exception isn't a possibility, because this is for an API that doesn't make use of Django Views, and process_exception only captures exceptions raised in views.

Answer (score 0):

Django already knows how to log unhandled errors with the full traceback. The default configuration is to send the report by mail to `settings.ADMINS` but you can reconfigure the logger to write to a log file, syslog, stderr or whatever. Complete doc is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/logging/

Comment: Seems good in theory, but I have yet to see a working example of that that doesn't have to leverage middleware in some way. I'm not sure why. If you have one that you've seen work in the wild, I'm all ears.

Comment: It's nothing theoretical and you dont have to roll your own middleware to log unhandled exceptions. All it takes is configuring the handler you want and adding it to the `django.requests` logger in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `process_exception` hook. If you call `sys.exc_info()` from inside `process_exception`, it will return the exception data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception